# How to get all users using ldap?

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I trying to use ldap & spring, and I have some questions.
I need list of users and list of groups. What the query I should to use? 
I trying to use several filters, such as `(objectClass=person)` or `(objectClass=*)`, but results were not what I expected. `(objectClass=person)` not listed all users , but listed other information. In other words, the result is a set of attributes, which included the necessary elements and unnecessary (if I use filter `objectClass=person`, result of the filter - set `"CN=Users, CN=MyUser" CN=MyUser` - is `user`, but `CN=Users` - is `group`).
How to list all user names (or uid) and all list of groups?

Comment: I can't make head or tail of this question starting at 'for example'. Try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(&(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=Person))` for a User.  Computers are Users too, but not people.