# Returning all Users from AD instead of users from groups in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to ammend the following code to return all users from AD instead of Domain Admins:

Original Code:

```
 $objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
   $objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
$strFilter = "(&(sAMAccountName=Domain Admins))"

$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$DomainAdminDN = ($objSearcher.FindOne()).Properties.distinguishedname

$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 10000000
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=$DomainAdminDN))"
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter

return ($objSearcher.FindAll())
```

}

I have made the following changes but it seems to return every object in AD instead of just users in AD

```
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
$strFilter = "(&objectCategory=user(sAMAccountName=Users))"

$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$DomainAdminDN = ($objSearcher.FindOne()).Properties.distinguishedname

$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 10000000
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=$DomainAdminDN))"
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter

return ($objSearcher.FindAll())
```

}

All Help Welcome!

Comment: Curious if you looked at the ActiveDirectory module for powershell?  Might make this a lot easier.

Comment: Your LDAP filter should be `(&(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=Person)(memberOf=$DomainAdminDN))` Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226317/how-to-get-all-users-using-ldap

Comment: Thanks @Santiago, when I changed it to that I ended up with this error

Comment: An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: The (&(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=Person)(memberOf=)) search filter is invalid..
+ return ($objSearcher.FindAll())
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Director...sultsEnumerator:ResultsEnumerator) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadEnumeration

Comment: Any ideas why or how to fix it?

Comment: You cant have an empty value - your `(memberOf=)` doesn't have a value. Either add one or remove the filter term.

Comment: memberOf should be "Domain Users" (find the DN for this and hardcode it in).  `distinguishedName` will look like `CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com`

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveDirectory module is made for this.

```
    $AllUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Server MyDomain -properties *
    $AllUsers | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation 'c:\temp\allusers.csv'
```

Depending on the size of your domain, this could bog your DC for a minute or two.  So if you have thousands of users, do this at an off time.

Instructions on how to load the module are on the [Microsoft Docs site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to the AD module.

```
([adsisearcher]"(&(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=Person))").findall().properties
```

This will list all user objects. The object returned is type `System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyCollection`

Here's a little function to create a `PSCustomObject` and get rid of the `{}` around the values.

```
([adsisearcher]"(&(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=Person))").findall().properties | ForEach-Object {
    $ht = [ordered]@{}
    foreach($entry in $_.getenumerator()){
        $ht.add($entry.name,$($entry.value))
    }
    [PSCustomObject]$ht
}
```